Definition of variance in DDPM
Does there exist any proof for these equations?
\begin{align*}
q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} | \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0)
&= \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}; \tilde{\boldsymbol{\mu}}_t(\mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0), \tilde{\beta}_t \mathbf{I}), \tag{6}
\end{align*}
where $\tilde{\boldsymbol{\mu}}_t(\mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0) := \frac{\sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_{t-1}}\beta_t}{1-\bar{\alpha}_t} \mathbf{x}_0 + \frac{\sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_{t}}(1-\bar{\alpha}_{t-1})}{1-\bar{\alpha}_t} \mathbf{x}_t $ and $\tilde{\beta}_t := \frac{1-\bar{\alpha}_{t-1}}{1-\bar{\alpha}_t} \beta_t$.
I understand it as condition probability with multiple conditions, which is defined as:
$$ \mathbb{P}(A | B, C) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B \cap C)}{\mathbb{P}(B \cap C)} $$
$\mathbf{x}_0$ is as I understand from real data distribution that may not be Gaussian. $\mathbf{x}_t$ is a combination of $\mathbf{x}_0$ distribution and Gaussian distribution parametrised by $\beta_t$.
Similarly in the DDIM is not the proof behind the mean and variance definition:
$$ q_{\sigma}(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} | \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0)
= \mathcal{N}\left( \sqrt{\alpha_{t-1}}\mathbf{x}_0 + \sqrt{1 - \alpha_{t-1} - \sigma_t^2} \cdot \frac{\mathbf{x}_t - \alpha_t \mathbf{x}_0}{\sqrt{1 - \alpha_t}}, \sigma_t^2 \mathbf{I} \right) $$
And the mean expressed in equation DDIM must be equivalent for $\tilde{\boldsymbol{\mu}}_t(\mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0)$, proof?
References

Ho, Jonathan, Ajay Jain, and Pieter Abbeel. "Denoising diffusion probabilistic models." Advances in neural information processing systems 33 (2020): 6840-6851.

Song, Jiaming, Chenlin Meng, and Stefano Ermon. "Denoising diffusion implicit models." arXiv preprint arXiv:2010.02502 (2020).


Thanks.

Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please take moment to give this posting a read to learn how to ask a good question.

As you're new to the community, I've replaced the image links with the corresponding formulas this time. Using images or links for formulas is strongly discouraged here. To learn about writing mathematics on this site, please refer to these resources: here, here, here and here.

Thank you very much for your help with the pictures.

I think I forgot to answer your question about DDIM. For the conditional distribution part, you can  do the same calculation but now following how $\mathbf{x}_t$ is defined in the DDIM paper. Then, does the conditional mean for DDIM equivalent to that of DDPM? Actually, NO. Although DDPM and DDIM have the same "probability path" $p(\mathbf{x}t|\mathbf{x}0){t\in[1:T]}$ as a function of $t$, they come up with different joint distribution $p(\mathbf{x}{[1:T]}|\mathbf{x}_0)$, with that of DDPM being essentially a "random walk" while that of DDIM being "almost deterministic".

This difference in the choice of joint distribution leads to the difference in the way instances of $\mathbf{x}_t$'s are progressively sampled. This, in turn, leads to different models (or more precisely, different samplers, because a model trained in one way can be converted to the other way in a systematic manner.).

Note that in the DDPM paper, the joint distribution $q$ of $(\mathbf{x}_t)_{[1:T]}$ given $\mathbf{x}_0$ is specified by the graphical model
$$ (\mathbf{x}_0) 
\longrightarrow (\mathbf{x}_1) 
\longrightarrow (\mathbf{x}_2) 
\longrightarrow \cdots 
\longrightarrow (\mathbf{x}_T), $$
or equivalenty,
$$ q(\mathbf{x}_{[1:T]} | \mathbf{x}_0) = \prod_{t\in[1:T]} q(\mathbf{x}_t|\mathbf{x}_{t-1}) $$
with $q(\mathbf{x}_t|\mathbf{x}_{t-1}) = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}_t; \sqrt{1-\beta_t} \mathbf{x}_{t-1}, \beta_t \mathbf{I}) $. By the property of gaussian distribution, this joint distribution can be realized by the "reparametrization trick" as follows:
Reparametrization Trick. Let $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_1, \ldots, \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_T$ be independent standard normal vectors, i.e., $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_t \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I})$ for each $t$. Also, given $\mathbf{x}_0$, we recursively define $\mathbf{x}_{[1:T]}$ by
$$ \mathbf{x}_t = \sqrt{1-\beta_t} \mathbf{x}_{t-1} + \sqrt{\beta_t} \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_t, \quad t = 1, \ldots, T.$$
Then the joint distribution of $\mathbf{x}_{[1:T]}$ given $\mathbf{x}_0$ is precisely $q(\mathbf{x}_{[1:T]}|\mathbf{x}_0)$. Moreover, this allows us to manipulate the distribution at the level of random variables. Indeed, defining $\alpha_t = 1 - \beta_t$ and $\bar{\alpha}_t = \prod_{s\in[1:t]} \alpha_s$ as in the paper, then the above recursive formula yields
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}_t
&= \sqrt{\beta_t} \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_t + \sqrt{\alpha_t} \mathbf{x}_{t-1} \\
&= \sqrt{\beta_t} \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_t + \sqrt{\alpha_t \beta_{t-1}} \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_{t-1} + \sqrt{\alpha_t \alpha_{t-1}} \mathbf{x}_{t-2} \\
&\quad \vdots \\
&= \sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_t} \Biggl( \mathbf{x}_0 + \sum_{s\in[1:t]} \frac{\sqrt{\beta_s }}{\sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_s}} \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_s \Biggr). \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Since any linear combination of jointly gaussian variables is again gaussian, this shows that $\mathbf{x}_t$ is also a gaussian variable. Then the distribution of $\mathbf{x}_t$ is completely specified by its mean and covariance matrix, which is easily computed from the properties of normal distribution. The upshot is that
$$ \mathbb{E}_{q(\mathbf{x}_{[1:T]}|\mathbf{x}_0)} [\mathbf{x}_t] = \sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_t} \mathbf{x}_0 $$
and
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Cov}_{q(\mathbf{x}_{[1:T]}|\mathbf{x}_0)} (\mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_t)
&= \bar{\alpha}_t \sum_{s\in[1:t]} \frac{\beta_s}{\bar{\alpha}_s} \mathbf{I} \\
&= \bar{\alpha}_t \sum_{s\in[1:t]} \left( \frac{1}{\bar{\alpha}_s} - \frac{1}{\bar{\alpha}_{s-1}} \right) \mathbf{I} \\
&= (1 - \bar{\alpha}_t) \mathbf{I} .
\end{align*}
This proves Equation $(4)$ of the DDPM paper.
Proving Equation $\text{(6)}$. It is well-known that conditioning a gaussian variable by another jointly normal variable leads to a gaussian distribution. More precisely,

Lemma. Let $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}_x, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{xx})$ and $\mathbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}_y, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{yy})$ be jointly gaussian random vectors. Also, let $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{yx} = \mathbf{Cov}(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{x})$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{xy} = \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{yx}^{\top} = \mathbf{Cov}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$ be the cross-covariances between $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{x}$. Then
$$ (\mathbf{y}\mid\mathbf{x}) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_y + \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{yx}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{xx}^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \mu_x), \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{yy} - \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{yx}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{xx}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{xy}). $$

Although this fact is part of the standard knowledge covered in many books, including Bishop, I included its proof at the end.
Returning to the argument, the lemma tells that the law of $q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1} | \mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0)$ is also gaussian. To compute its mean and variance, we compute:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Cov}(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_t)
&= \mathbb{Cov}(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}, \sqrt{\alpha_t} \mathbf{x}_{t-1} + \sqrt{1-\alpha_t} \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_t) \\
&= \sqrt{\alpha_t} \mathbb{Cov}(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_{t-1}) \\
&= \sqrt{\alpha_t} (1 - \bar{\alpha}_{t-1}) \mathbf{I},
\end{align*}
where the expectation $\mathbb{E}$ is taken with respect to the law $q(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_t| \mathbf{x}_0)$. Then
\begin{align*}
\tilde{\boldsymbol{\mu}}_t(\mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0)
&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}_{t-1}]
+ \mathbb{Cov}(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_t)
\mathbb{Cov}(\mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_t)^{-1}
(\mathbf{x}_t - \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}_{t}]) \\
&= \sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_{t-1}} \mathbf{x}_0 + \frac{\sqrt{\alpha_t} (1 - \bar{\alpha}_{t-1})}{1-\bar{\alpha}_t}(\mathbf{x}_t - \sqrt{\bar{\alpha}_t} \mathbf{x}_0 )
\end{align*}
Simplifying the last expression yields the desired formula for $\tilde{\boldsymbol{\mu}}_t(\mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0)$. Similarly, the variance $\tilde{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}_t(\mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0)$ is given by
\begin{align*}
\tilde{\boldsymbol{\Sigma}}_t(\mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_0)
&= \mathbb{Cov}(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_{t-1})
+ \mathbb{Cov}(\mathbf{x}_{t-1}, \mathbf{x}_t)
\mathbb{Cov}(\mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_t)^{-1} \mathbb{Cov}(\mathbf{x}_t, \mathbf{x}_{t-1}) \\
&= \left[ (1 - \bar{\alpha}_{t-1}) - \frac{(\sqrt{\alpha_t} (1 - \bar{\alpha}_{t-1}))^2 }{1 - \bar{\alpha}_t} \right] \mathbf{I}.
\end{align*}
Again, simplifying the last line yields $\tilde{\beta}_t \mathbf{I}$.

Proof of Lemma. Let
\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol{\mu}_{y|x} &= \mu_y + \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{yx}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{xx}^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \mu_x), \\
\mathbf{z}
&= (\mathbf{y} - \mu_y) - \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{yx}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{xx}^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \mu_x).
\end{align*}
Then we observe that

$\mathbf{y} = \boldsymbol{\mu}_{y|x} + \mathbf{z}$.
$\boldsymbol{\mu}_{y|x}$ is a deterministic function of $\mathbf{x}$ only.
$\boldsymbol{\mu}_{y|x}$ and $\mathbf{z}$ are jointly normal and $\mathbb{Cov}(\boldsymbol{\mu}_{y|x},\mathbf{z}) = \mathbf{0}$. In particular, $\mathbf{z}$ is independent of $\boldsymbol{\mu}_{y|x}$. By this independence, we also have $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{z}\mid x] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{z}] = \mathbf{0}$.

Hence, conditional on $\mathbf{x}$, we find that $\mathbf{y}$ is the sum of "known value" $\boldsymbol{\mu}_{y|x}$ and the centered gaussian vector $\mathbf{z}$. From this we easily read out the mean and covariance matrix of $(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x})$.
(Remark. The formula for $\mathbf{z}$ is essentially the Gram–Schmidt orthogonalization in linear algebra.)
